# Using permissionOverwrite to give role(s) channel specific permissions

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a Ticket Bot and I have run into an issue with my `permissionOverwrites`, I want to give my Staff permission to view and send messages but they ways I have tried do not work sadly.

Here is the code:

```
permissionOverwrites: [
    {
        id: user.id,
        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
    },
    {
        id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone,
        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
    },
    {
        id: reaction.message.guild.roles.staff,
        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you can just put in the role id like this:

```
{
   id: 'ROLE-ID',
   allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message.channel.createOverwrite(RoleResolvable, {
  FLAG: true
})
  .then(channel => console.log(channel.permissionOverwrites.get(message.author.id)))
  .catch(console.error);
```

The [RoleResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable) can be the Role ID (snowflake) or the role, you can fetch the role like this:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Staff");
```

The flags you can pass through are [Bitwise Permission Flags](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permissions-bitwise-permission-flags).

Comment: so just doing const srole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Staff"); and then adding in id: srole.id wont work?

Comment: You can use it like `.createOverwrite('12398123908123', {` with the RoleID, or you can just do
`const role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Staff");
.createOverwrite(role, {`